# reducing similar top results in solr result output

Tags: solr, fieldcollapsing

I have a search in solr that is returning about 1500 documents. These documents are basically products. For example, I have a bunch of womens shoes in my dataset. My dataset has a wide variety of shoes for women, but it also has some very similar results, for instance, size 11 womens nike trainers, size 10 womens nike trainers, etc... Now, when I search for womens shoes, solr scoring causes a certain set of these results to bubble to the top that are all very similar.. For instance, all the colors of one particular shoe model might come to the top. They are definitely different products, but I would prefer to get a wider variety of results than just every color of nike trainer shoes.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Note, I don't want to eliminate all the individually colored products. When someone searches for blue womens nike trainers, I want them to get the blue model as the top result. I'm using the dismax query as my main query. What I would like to do is basically boost on some kind of "uniqueness of name compared to other results" factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either collapse on fields like color or so:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

or you can use near duplicate detection when indexing:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication

http://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/detect-stolen-and-duplicate-tweets-with-solr/

the latter algorithm is implemented in jetwick for tweets, so it should work for titles, but not performant enough for big documents (so only plagiarism detection for 'short' strings). for long text you'll need local sensitive hashing:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing